# GetElementById return incorrect nodes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm encountered a little problem (I don't know if I did some mistake or if is a bug) while parsing [this](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/champions-league/paok-spartak-moscow-pIXFEt8o/?r=1#ah;2) page.

I'm trying to get all the `a` tag available in this table:

[image]

so for achieve this, I wrote this code:

```
`var d = doc.GetElementbyId("odds-data-table");
HtmlNodeCollection listItems = d.SelectNodes("//a");`
```

in particular `d` contains the table structure that I want:

[image]

but the `listItems` variable doesn't contains the link of the table but of the whole html page, and this is pretty weird. I tried different case:

```
d.SelectNodes("a") : return null
d.SelectNodes("//a") : return all the link of the page 
d.SelectNodes("/a") : return null
```

what is wrong?
And I would ask also which type of plugin or system did you use for HtmlAgilityPack documentation, is really stunning, thanks.

Comment: Try `d.SelectNodes(".//a")`

Comment: do you want all `href` in your `listItems`?

Comment: @ershoaib yep all the href of `odds-data-table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read `Attributes` property for each of your `HtmlNode` from your `HtmlNodeCollection` like

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
var d = doc.GetElementbyId("odds-data-table");
HtmlNodeCollection listItems = d.SelectNodes(".//a");

//This list contains all your href values
List<string> hrefs = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in listItems)
{
      var href = item.Attributes["href"].Value;
      hrefs.Add(href);
}
```

Comment: @Charanoglu, view the answer may it help you :)

Comment: it works as expected and gives me a list of hrefs and that OP want

Comment: @I didn't put the downvote but the problem is that `d.SelectNodes("//a")` return the link of the whole page instead of the table

Comment: did u noticed that there is no any link assigned on each item in table

Comment: please clear me : you want <a> element or <a> elements href value?

Comment: I just need to extract all the `a` tag of `odds-data-table`, of course each `a` tag have as attribute `href`..  I don't know why is too hard to understand

Comment: could you please add your code instead of image in OP? so its easy to understand what you did so far

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177645/discussion-between-charanoglu-and-ershoaib).

Comment: the black mode gives cool to my eyes bcoz my eyes are white light conscious
and glad to hear you have get rid from your problem :)